# jQuery - Finding the element index relative to its container

Tags: jquery, indexing

Here's my HTMl structure:

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="inner-1">
      <img />
      <img />
      <img />
   </div>

   <div id="inner-2">
      <img />
      <img class="selected" />
      <img />
   </div>

   <div id="inner-3">
      <img />
      <img />
      <img />
   </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is get the index of the img.selected element relative to the #main div. So in this example, the index should be 4 (assuming 0 based index) and not 1.

My usual way to go about getting indexes is using `$element.prevAll().length` but, obviously, that will return the index relative to the #inner-2 div.

I've tried using `$('img.selected').prevAll('#main').length` but that's returning 0 :/

Answer (score 9):

This will work; it finds the index of the selected image within the set of all `img` tags inside `#main`.

```
$('#main img').index('img.selected');
```

Comment: FYI `index()` can take a selector so `$("#main img").index("img.selected")` is valid.

Comment: @cletus Of course :| Updated answer, thanks for catching that.